# Formatting error while creating report using Shell Script

Tags: sql, sh

HI all I am fairly new to Shell Scripting .. I was testing a sample report in which I was trying to spool the output of sql query embedded in shell script. here is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

ORACLE_ACCESS=hr/hr@xe
# Report file location
FILE_LOCATION=/home/$USER/Documents/loaddata/
#File Name
FILE_NAME=Report_`date +%y%m%d`.csv

sqlplus -s $ORACLE_ACCESS <<EOF 2>log.txt
set serveroutout on
set echo off
set first_name format A120

spool ${FILE_LOCATION}${FILE_NAME}
select first_name,last_name 
from employees;
exit;
EOF

sql_error=$?
if [$sql_error !=0]; then
   echo "Error"
   exit 1
fi
```

However I am getting a pretty badly formatted output.

below is the sample

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME

---

Ellen                Abel
Sundar               Ande
Mozhe                Atkinson
David                Austin
Hermann              Baer
Shelli               Baida
Amit                 Banda
Elizabeth            Bates
Sarah                Bell
David                Bernstein
Laura                Bissot

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME

---

Harrison             Bloom
Alexis               Bull
Anthony              Cabrio
Gerald               Cambrault
Nanette              Cambrault
John                 Chen
Kelly                Chung
Karen                Colmenares

My intended output should look something like below

First_name   Last_name
Atlas        Levine
John         Doe

can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your intended output like

```
First_name Last_name
Atlas Levine
John Doe
```

If so you can use something like `set pagesize 10000` or something large so that the header doesnt get repeated. If you want to skip the header you can just set it to `0` You can refer the answers and links in [Formatting output of queries in SQLPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751843/formatting-output-of-queries-in-sqlplus) along with many other similar questions